# using powershell to set an event logs "Maximum Size" action

Tags: c#, powershell, event-log

When viewing an Event Logs properties (in Server 2008) you can set three actions for what to happen when the maximum event log size has been reached:

- Overwrite events as needed
- Archive the log when full
- Do not overwrite events

Using Powershell I can use [limit-eventlog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849843.aspx) to set the event log retention to set the `OverflowAction` to DoNotOverwrite or OverwriteAsNeeded, but I cannot seem to be able to get the `Archive the log when full` action selected.

Any ideas how I could select this option via powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way (IMO) is to modifying the `registry`. Here an example to set 'Archive the log when full' action for the Application log:

```
new-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application `
-name AutoBackupLogFiles -Value 1 -PropertyType 'dword'
```

if the options have been selected previously, the key is already present so just need set to 1 the key value:

```
set-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application `
    -name AutoBackupLogFiles -Value 1
```

Comment: in addition to @Christian's answer, you have to set the `Retention` value under `event log key` to `0xffffffff`. For doing this you can use the code that was written in @Christian's answer.<br/><br/>
Addiitional information is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)